# how to drag and drop UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop, uibutton

I want to drag and drop `UIbutton` in my app like iPhone main screen icons.

I can do this but while clicking the button it should perform an action. But this action is also called while dragging the button. I am using `UIControlEventTouchDown` for touch action and `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` for dragging the button.

Comment: Try changing your touch action to TouchUpInside instead.

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use UIControlEventTouchUpInside for this action instead touch down.
In UIControlEventTouchDragInside you may change the shared variable named like "dragPerformed" to YES, and then, if it is NO perform click button action in UIControlEventTouchUpInside, if YES - do nothing (that is drag) and turn it to NO